# Music in Webview Activity kill when press back button to home activity

Tags: android

I am coding the play mp3(Flash Embedded) in WebView(Second Activity), I can play the music in WebView as usually, but when I press back buttom to First Activity the music in Second Activity in WebView still playing, then I go to Second Activity again in WebView to stop the music but it's appear the new mp3 play list screen, I can't stop the music.

So, how can I kill the process when I press back button to First Activity(Home Screen)

Best Regards,
Virak

Comment: I think you can call finish() in your on pause.

Comment: as I am really new to android. Could you please give me some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this function in your class. actually this will override onpause.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: I already added your code in my Activity 2, but when I press back button to first activity the program hanging and force to close.

Comment: @user1377695 Your program will force close if an error occurs. Add the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: This did not work for me, the music is still playing in `WebView`.

Answer (score 0):

This was the only thing that worked for me. To use the `destroy()` method of `WebView` in the `onPause()` lifecycle method.

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    wView.destroy();
}
```